# Video is not playing in YoutubePlayer Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am making an app which uses Youtube player fragment. It is loaded but video is not getting played. Here is my code:

**Youtube.java (Fragment)**

```
public class Youtube extends YouTubePlayerFragment {


    public Youtube() {
    }

    public static Youtube newInstance(String url) {

        Youtube frag = new Youtube();

        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("url", url);

        frag.setArguments(b);
        frag.init();

        return frag;
    }

    private void init() {

        initialize(API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
                if (!wasRestored) {
                    player.cueVideo(getArguments().getString("url"));
                   // player.play();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Activity**:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Youtube f = Youtube.newInstance("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o49aHgzTOGw");
        FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(f,"Fragment").commit();
    }
```

**Layout**:

```
<FrameLayout>
    <fragment class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
              android:id="@+id/Fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Where I am going wrong. I am not able to figure it out. Do I need to extend `YoutubeBaseActivity`? How to achieve this?

Comment: Activtiy layout:<fragment

    class="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
    android:id="@+id/Fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

</FrameLayout>

Answer (score 1):

I think you should write the code in official way. Take look at [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications#Simple_PlayerFragment), and download the zip file(sample applications included in the `YouTubeAndroidAPIDemo` package) [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads) to get the sample. And take look at `FragmentDemoActivity`.

Basically, you need to do the `Activity` which include `YoutubePlayerFragment` as follows:

```
public class FragmentDemoActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragments_demo);

    YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment =
        (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
  }

  @Override
  public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
      boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
      player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);
  }
}
```

YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity :

```
public abstract class YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

  private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

  @Override
  public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
      YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
      errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
      String errorMessage = String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
      Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
      // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
      getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);
    }
  }

  protected abstract YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider();

}
```

And the `fragments_demo.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <fragment
      android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerFragment"
      android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```