# How to solve issue regarding youtube api in android app

Tags: java, android, youtube

There is some problem regarding working with youtube API in my code. Here what am trying is to call [`YoutubeFragmentActivity`](https://github.com/priyajain8296/test_youtube_api/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/towncitycards/activities/YouTubeFragmentActivity.java) inside my [`Tab2frag.java`](https://github.com/priyajain8296/test_youtube_api/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/towncitycards/fragments/Tab2Frag.java) which is not working in my case.
To be specific about my problem: From tab 2 I am passing youtube URL using `data.putString("youtube_details", youtube_url1);`. which is comming from `OnPostExecute` inside `Show_data` class like this

```
youtube_url = jobj.opt("youtube_detail").toString();
     youtube_url1=youtube_url.replace("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=","");
```

`YoutubeFragmentActivity`. I am get it `YOU_TUBE = extras.getString("youtube_details");`

Here is my code for **YouTubeFragmentActivity**

```
   public class YouTubeFragmentActivity extends Fragment {
    private FragmentActivity myContext;
    private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private static String YOU_TUBE;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            myContext = (FragmentActivity) activity;
        }

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }


        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_you_tube_api, container, false);
            Bundle extras = getArguments();
            YOU_TUBE = extras.getString("youtube_details");
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@"+YOU_TUBE+"@@@@@@@2");
            YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("DEVELOPER_KEY", new OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    if (!b) {
                        YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                        YPlayer.loadVideo(YOU_TUBE);
                        YPlayer.play();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            });
         return rootView;
        }


}
```

---

In `Tab2Frag` I am passing URL using Bundle for youtube player which is working. But a video is not playing.I am trying it many times but still not able to solve the issue.

If someone can solve it.It would be great for me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Video is not playing in YoutubePlayer Fragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218732/video-is-not-playing-in-youtubeplayer-fragment)

Comment: I am editing it

Answer (score 0):

Have you debuggued it? 
Sometimes the bundle its reset when passing to some places.
Check the bundle permissions, life time and call.

Comment: While debugging application it is giving me `youTubeFragmentActivity.setArguments(data);  youTubeFragmentActivity: "YouTubeFragmentActivity{f8a5911}"
data: "Bundle[{youtube_details=null})]"`

Comment: How can I solve this issue link for complete code [link](https://github.com/priyajain8296/test_youtube_api/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/towncitycards/fragments/Tab2Frag.java)